# does rospy support rosparam update callbacks?

Tags: ros-melodic, rospy, rosparam

Using `rospy`/`ROS1`, I would like a callback when a certain parameter on the `ROS1` parameter server is changed.

The closest I could find was `get_param_cached` which probably has some sort of parameter subscription under the hood, but the details appeared a little cloudy at first sight.

Are `rosparam` callbacks supported in any `rospy` APIs?
Or do you have a code snippet that can show me how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Adding parameter events is a new feature added in ROS 2 for . Part of the [parameter design document](https://design.ros2.org/articles/ros_parameters.html#parameter-events) It's a new feature and not available in ROS 1, either rospy or roscpp.

You will need to do some sort of polling process if you want to monitor for a change.